# Keep getting 400 Bad Request error when trying out AJAX on custom theme

Tags: ajax

So I've been working on a custom theme I'm building, for which I'm trying to implement an AJAX powered search presentation. I have built everything according to several tutorials and guides, but when inspecting the call to admin-ajax, it keeps returning 400 errors ... I'm fresh out of ideas and was hoping someone could shed some light on the issue here.

**functions.php**

```
function load_search_results(){
$q = $_REQUEST['query'];
$post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    's' => $q,
);

$search = new WP_Query($args);

if ($search->have_posts()){
    echo json_encode('has posts');
} else {
    echo json_encode('no posts found');
}

wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_search_results', 'load_search_results');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_search_results', 'load_search_results');
```

**Enqueueing the scripts in functions.php as well**

```
wp_register_script('ajax-search', THEME_DIR .'/assets/js/ajax/search.ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false);
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-search');
wp_localize_script('ajax-search', 'myAjax', array('ajax_url' =>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

**search.ajax.js**

```
(function($) {

$(document).on('submit', '.controls-search', function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    var $input = $form.find('input[name="s"]');
    var query = $input.val();
    var $content = $('.licence');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        post_type: 'shuffle_licence',
        url: myAjax.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'load_search_results',
            query: query
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $input.prop('disabled', true);
            $content.addClass('loading')
        },
        succes: function(response){
            $input.prop('disabled', false);
            $content.removeClass('loading');
            $content.html(response);
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/json',
    });

    return false;

});

}(jQuery))
```

Comment: The `post_type` property of your AJAX request should be in `data`, otherwise `$_REQUEST['post_type']` won’t be set. Also, this type of request should be GET, not POST. Only use POST for requests that have a ‘side effect’ like adding something to the database. You’re just retrieving data, so get is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I deleted two lines:

```
dataType: 'html',
contentType: 'application/json'
```

When I deleted those, I got an 200 response with the appropriate response text.

Comment: If you’re expecting JSON as a response then dataType needs to be `'json'`.

Comment: Can you click on the check mark beside the answer to accept it?